# Python interpreter, Pygtk and GtkGrid

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

i've to use GtkGrid because i need to draw a rectangle for every item i have.
(i would add a Drawing area to every GtkGrid's cell and draw the rectangle by cairographics library)

But there was a problem: python 2.7 doesn't support GtkGrid, so i surfed the web and i simply changed the first line of my file (and installed python3.3).

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.3

try:  
    import pygtk  
    pygtk.require("2.0")  
except:  
    print("PyGtk Not Availible")
    sys.exit(1)

try:  
    import gtk  
    import gtk.glade  
except:  
    print("GTK Not Availible")
    sys.exit(1)
```

Now it cannot rescue anymore Pygtk or GTK libraries.. and with python2.7 all work fine..
Maybe the best solution would be to avoid newer python interpreters and change GtkGrid into something else..

Help me please

EDIT:: 
Just cut and pasted an example from Pygtk examples

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.3

# example drawingarea.py

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
import operator
import time
import string

class DrawingAreaExample:
    def __init__(self):
        window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        window.set_title("Drawing Area Example")
        window.connect("destroy", lambda w: gtk.main_quit())
        self.area = gtk.DrawingArea()
        self.area.set_size_request(400, 300)
        self.pangolayout = self.area.create_pango_layout("")
        self.sw = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        ...
```

With Python 2.7 it works, with Python 3.3: `No module named 'pygtk'`

Comment: I don't understand: why you say "Now it cannot rescue anymore Pygtk or GTK libraries." ?

Comment: Because the exception is raised and is printed "PyGtk Not Availible"

Comment: In my case no exception raised, strange... try without `try - except` and paste here the error. But wait, from shell you run: `python3.3 script.py`?

Comment: without try-except of course nothing is raised.. anyway check out the EDIT:: i'm going to write

Comment: What? without try-except you shoud receive the standard error in shell if you can't import a module, like this: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prova.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pygtk  
ImportError: No module named 'pygtk'
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make this clear: You have to decide wether you want to use the `gi.introspection` bindings (which are up to date and mostly autogenerated) or the `pygtk` wrapper around `gtk+-2.0` (hand crafted, as of now `pygtk3` is still work in progress, correct me if I am wrong).

**Mixing these will get you in trouble further or later.**

---

Also your initial issue was, `GtkGrid` (part of `gtk+-3.0`) was part of the `gi.introspection` bindings which (usually) require `Python 3.x.y`, whereas you used `pygtk2` with `Python 2.7.x`. Changing to `Python 3.3` just made the bindings availiable to you.

---

In `gtk2` `GtkGrid` was called `GtkTable`, see https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkTable.html.

Comment: Could you please explain "Mixing these will get you in trouble further or later."? Or maybe provide some link about this? Thanks!

Comment: Just an example, gtk2 and gtk3 use totally different drawing mechanics, allocation algorithms for the widgets and that might potentially can give you drawing glitches. Just an example. Also the API might have changed (i.e. consuming arguments vs user-has-to-take-car-of-cleanup).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8; -*-
from gi.repository import Gtk
grid = Gtk.Grid()
```

You need to use GTK+ 3, not python3.3 (in order to have a Gtk.Grid)... if i understand what you mean...

Edited.

Comment: It is working, thanks.
But is it safe? Why just **import gtk** was not enough? How this works?

Comment: Because gtk is from GTK+ 2 and `from gi.repository import Gtk` is from GTK+ 3. So if you need widget that are present only in GTK+ 3, you need to use `from gi.repository import Gtk` I'm new to Gtk developing, but i think this is the explanation.

Comment: By doing that you are opening a wormhole for a whole new kind of issues, see my answer for a detailed explanation.